# Does CoreData persist the data after I upgrade the app?

Tags: ios, core-data

Does CoreData persist the user data after I upgrade the app? Otherwise I'd need to write a web services with a db to persists the user data.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you store your data in the application's documents directory, you don't need to update your database or settings if you are just upgrading the app. If you delete the app from the device, then the documents is also deleted, in which case you will have to recreate your data.